# How set Custom path to browse & view content of it?

Tags: php, directory, include-path, jsonpath

In this code for **file manager script** I want to set the custom or optionality path/directory to view his folders and files.

So, how can I do that ?

```
function get_absolute_path($path) {
$path = str_replace(['/', '\\'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
$absolutes = [];
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if ('.' == $part) continue;
    if ('..' == $part) {
        array_pop($absolutes);
    } else {
        $absolutes[] = $part;
    }
}
return implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $absolutes);
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you want to achive? If you want to set a path, just change `$path` to what you want. Do you want to get some input from the user, such as `$_POST`? Please give an example of what you are trying to achieve and how your code reflects it

Comment: Hi bro, I just want to view the folder which it outside of the script folder.
for ex:
this is script dir:
www/filemanager/index.php
this is what i want to view in file manager: 
www/source/